# Differentiation by interpolation.

Tags: derivatives, interpolation

I am asked to show that the formula:
$$
f'(x)\sim \sum_{i=0}^n A_i f(x_i)
$$

which is derived from differentiating the interpolation polynomial
is similar to that derived from checking/evaluating the order of accuracy formulae and similar to that derived through Taylor expansion.
I have found the error in all these cases to be of the form:
$$e(x)=C f^{(k)}(x) h^n$$
which means that the error becomes zero for any polynomial of degree less than or equal to $k-1$.
Hence, for any such polynomial, the above formula could be rewritten thus:
$$f'(x)=\sum_{i=0}^n A_i f(x_i)$$
Now, as the error in the Taylor expansion would also be zero for such polynomial, $f(x)$ could be accurately replaced with:

$$
\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} f^{(i)}(x_0) \frac{(x-x_0)^i}{i!}
$$
Thus, the formula would hold and be similar.
Is this attempt correct? Am I missing something? Would sincerely appreciate some advice.

Comment: Do questions get answered often? Did I happen to post this to the wrong group?